# PushCounterPanel cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing, types, jpanel

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class PushCounter
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates the main program frame.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Push Counter");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.getContentPane().add(new PushCounterPanel());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public PushCounterPanel extends JFrame{

count = 0;
push = new JButton("Push Me!");
push.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
label = new JLabel("Pushes: " + count);
add(push);
add(label);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
setBackground(Color.cyan);
}
//*****************************************************************
// Represents a listener for button push (action) events.
//*****************************************************************
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Updates the counter and label when the button is pushed.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
count++;
label.setText("Pushes: " + count);
}
}
}
```

I keep getting the error  `PushCounterPanel`  cannot be resolved to a type on line twelve. Where am I going wrong here? I'm trying to create a random number generator whenever I click the button, but I cannot even seem to be able to get started.

Comment: Make sure PushCounterPanel is compiled. Having said that, why are you trying to add a JFrame to a JFrame? That makes no sense. Shouldn't your PushCounterPanel extend JPanel? Also, why are you posting all-left justified code? You will want to put in an effort to post only well-formatted code, since if we can read it, we can better understand it and help you.

Answer (score 2):

This won't compile:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public PushCounterPanel extends JFrame{
```

It should be

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

// need the class declaration    
public class PushCounterPanel extends JFrame{
```

Having said that, why are you trying to add a JFrame to a JFrame? That makes no sense. Shouldn't your PushCounterPanel extend JPanel?

So it **really** should be:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

// need the class declaration and that it extends JPanel    
public class PushCounterPanel extends JPanel {
```

Also the rest of yoru PushCounterPanel won't compile:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public PushCounterPanel extends JFrame{

count = 0;
push = new JButton("Push Me!");
push.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
label = new JLabel("Pushes: " + count);
add(push);
add(label);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
setBackground(Color.cyan);
}
//*****************************************************************
// Represents a listener for button push (action) events.
//*****************************************************************
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Updates the counter and label when the button is pushed.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
count++;
label.setText("Pushes: " + count);
}
}
}
```

You're using undeclared variables, you're trying to use statements naked in the class that belong within constructors or methods,... it's as if you're just throwing code at the wall and seeing what sticks, and that never works -- never try to add good code to bad code. Either use an IDE which will flag you immediately if your code doesn't compile, or if you're not allowed to use one, then compile your code frequently, and fix all compilation errors first before trying to add good code to bad. You should delete the PushCounterPanel class and start over. Start with this code skeleton:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PushCounterPanel extends JPanel {
    // TODO: put variables here 

    public PushCounterPanel() {
        // TODO finish this constructor
    }

    // TODO: put methods here
}
```

and fill the rest in.